# Different autocorrelation normalization values vs statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I'm testing some [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) implementations found in SO. I came across two great answers by [Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27558293/1391441) and [unubtu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298647/1391441). Both are very similar, except for the normalization used.

The former uses a `max` value, and the latter the `variance`. The results are quite different for some random uniform data as seen below.

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def acorr_unutbu(x):
    x = x - x.mean()
    autocorr = np.correlate(x, x, mode='full')[-x.size:]
    # Normalization
    autocorr /= (x.var() * (np.arange(x.size, 0, -1)))
    return autocorr

def acorr_joe(x):
    x = x - x.mean()
    # The original answer uses [x.size:], I changed it to [-x.size:] to match
    # the size of the other function
    autocorr = np.correlate(x, x, mode='full')[-x.size:]
    # Normalization
    autocorr /= autocorr.max()
    return autocorr

N = 1000
data = np.random.rand(N)

ac_joe = acorr_joe(data)
ac_unubtu = acorr_unutbu(data)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
axes[0].plot(ac_joe, label="joe")
axes[0].legend()
axes[1].plot(ac_unubtu, c='r', label="unutbu")
axes[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I can compare these two function with the [statsmodels autocorrelation function](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html?highlight=acf#statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf) `acf`, which shows that Joe's answer (with a minor modification shown in the code above) is using probably the correct normalization.

```
# Compare with statsmodels lags
lags = acf(data, nlags=N)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
axes[0].plot(ac_joe - lags, label="joe - SM")
axes[0].set_ylim(-.5, .5)
axes[0].legend()
axes[1].plot(ac_unubtu - lags, c='r', label="unutbu - SM")
axes[1].set_ylim(-.5, .5)
axes[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

What is the reason for the different normalization values used in these two autocorrelation functions?

Comment: I don't think we can say one or the other is correct, statsmodels has a `unbiased` option to switch. AFAIK, it's a bit like degrees of freedom correction when computing standard errors, without it's the maximum likelihood estimate and with it's the unbiased estimate of the variance. However, I don't remember specifics for acf.

Comment: I checked with the `autocorr.function()` of the [emcee](http://dfm.io/emcee/current/) package and it coincides with `statsmodels` and Joe's answer, so I'm more inclined to think it is the correct form. I trust unubtu's answers very much though, so I'm not 100% sure.